# multi-parameter 'in' in python

Tags: python

Let `L = [1,2,3,4]` be our list.

Then `1 in L` is `True`. `2 in L` is also `True`.

Is there a clean way to write `(1,2) in L` and have it come out true?

That is, given a list `L` and a test list `T` and the relation multi-in, if all members of `T` are in `L`, then `T multi-in L` is `True`, otherwise `T multi-in L` is `False`.

Of course I can write a multi-in function, but that seems ugly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to treat `(1,2)` and `L` as `set`s:

```
set((1,2)).issubset(L)
```

or, nicer if you understand the notation:

```
set((1,2)) <= set(L)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
all(x in L for x in [1, 2])
```

Unlike the set-based solutions, this (1) short-curcuits as soon as an element isn't found, (2) works for unhashable types and (3) reads out nice ;)

We can go improve complexity (`O(n*m)` currently) by going back to sets... although in a different way: Convert `L` to a set beforehand and you get `O(1)` membership test back (without needing a second set for the items to check for).

Comment: Do we know that `issubset` or `<=` don't short circuit?

Comment: @Andrew: It certainly will create two complete sets. I'd expect `issubset` to short-curcuit, but that cuts the third iteration (1. L -> set 2. items -> set 3. issubset) short - as opposed to the second (1. L -> set 2. genexpr).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
set((1,2)).issubset(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sets:

```
  s = set([1,2])
  l = set([1,2,3,4])

  s.issubset(l)
```

The `.issubset()` method will tell you if all the elements in one set exist in another.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers above.  Another possibility is:

```
all(x in L for x in [1,2,3,4])
```

I'm not dutch, but that's the "single obvious way to do it" to me.