# The python version of R's %in% function

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have an 1D integer array of "factors" which mean different things.  Sometimes multiple numbers mean the same thing:

```
import numpy as np

vec  = np.arange(1, 10)
comps = {
  'good': (3,),
  'bad': (4, 5, 9,),
  'ok': (2, 3,)
}

result = {}
for name in comps.keys():
    result[name] = np.zeros(len(vec), 'bool')
    for i, v in enumerate(vec):
        result[name][i] = v in comps[name]
```

This is the desired output.  However as `vec` gets large and the number of keys in `comps` goes up, this becomes quite slow.  Plus, its yucky... In `R` there is the `%in%` function:

```
vec = 1:10
comp = list(
    good = 3,
    bad = c(4:5, 9),
    ok = 2:3
)

lapply(comp, function(x) vec %in% x)
```

Which does the elementwise comparison between every value on the left side to each value in the right and returns the "logical or" result as a boolean vector the same length as `vec`.

I can get closer and cleaner using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.DataFrame({'vec': vec})

result = {}
for name in comps.keys():
    result[name] = DF.vec.apply(lambda x: x in comps[name])
```

Similar to [this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972735/multi-parameter-in-in-python) but I want the elementwise array rather than a single boolean as my result.

What is the best way to do this in python? (numpy? pandas?)

Comment: is 3 intentionally good and ok?

Comment: @AndyHayden It sure is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this using a dictionary comprehension (and the Series [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method):

```
pd.DataFrame({k: df.vec.isin(v) for k, v in comps.iteritems()})
```

Comment: I knew there was something, I just couldn't find it!  FWIW the `isin` method is about 10 times faster than using `apply` on my particular dataset.